# How do you add a condition like Count or Countif to limit in Query function?

Tags: google-sheets-formula, google-query-language

```
=query(B8:BQ293,"Select D Order by E Desc limit 5",-1)
```

The following works, but I want to add something to limit, so that 5 isn't a static variable, but based on some condition on another column.

What I want is to return a sorted column "D" based on column E like described, but D variables are longer than column E, and I just want to limit it to the length of column E.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
=query(B8:BQ293, "Select D Order by E Desc limit "&counta(E:E), -1)
```

Comment: Thank you that was very helpful.  Sorry for the late reply.